# using PreSendRequestHeaders Event in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, global-asax

I tried to assign the PreSendRequestHeaders Event in the global.asax file in the "Application_Start" method. But this does not work.

```
private void Application_Start()
{
    PreSendRequestHeaders += OnPreSendRequestHeaders;           
}

private void OnPreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // this is not called
}
```

The OnPreSendRequestHeaders is not called, why?
Is it possible to assign the PreSendRequestHeaders method in the global.asax?

Answer (score 11):

Just use:

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(Object source, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Or instantiate the handler:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    PreSendRequestHeaders += new EventHandler(OnPreSendRequestHeaders);
}

protected void OnPreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // should work now
}
```

Comment: Have you tried that? When I do that my OnPreSendRequestHeaders method is never called. What have you done to get this to work?

Comment: The first one works perfectly for me, but the second one does not (just as @Chris' initial question says)

Comment: **Never** hook up event handlers in Application_Start. ASP.NET creates multiple instances of your Global class so that multiple HTTP requests can be handled simultaneously, but Application_Start is called for only one of those instances. This means that your event handlers would only be in effect for one of the Global instances, not all of them.